# How do you calculate primary angles in wheel alignment for a particular chassis?

Tags: suspension, steering, alignment

We are trying to make a "efficycle" with a tadpole design. How should we select all the basic parameters for it like camber, caster, roll center etc.?
Is there a range of values for a specific design or sizes? or do we first make a virtual model and adjust all the parameters one by one after each simulation (I understand that it's a stupid idea to do that but that's the only one in my mind currently )